# Sorting by Subarray type value and then alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
$array = [
    'field1' => [
        '#type' => 'text',
        '#label' => 'Field 11',
    ],
    'field4' => [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#label' => 'Field 4',
    ],
    'field12' => [
        '#type' => 'text',
        '#label' => 'Field 12',
    ],
    'field3' => [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#label' => 'Field 3',
    ],
    'field18' => [
        '#type' => 'text',
        '#label' => 'Field 18',
    ],
];
```

I would like to sort this array in such a way where all the fields of type `fieldset` are at the bottom. At the same time, I would like the text fields (which are on top) to be sorted alphabetically by the `#label` and the fieldsets (which should be at the bottom) should also be sorted alphabetically by the label. This is what I had so far.

```
ksort($array);
uasort($array, function($field1) {
    if ($field1['#type'] !== 'fieldset') {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
});
```

Sorting the array by the key value successfully sorts my entire array alphabetically. But once I add the `uasort`, although my `fieldset`'s are at the bottom, the alphabetical order is no longer present.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use usort with 2 conditions

```
 usort($array, function ($i1, $i2) { 
                 // compare types 
                 $r = ($i1['#type'] == 'fieldset' ? 1 : 0) -  ($i2['#type'] == 'fieldset' ? 1 : 0); 
                 // if both are (or not) fieldset (r == 0), compare labels
                 return $r ? $r : strcmp($i1['#label'], $i2['#label']);  } );
```

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work correctly. The fieldsets are at the bottom, but nothing is being sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, that was my fault. The key value I should have compared to was `#title`, not `#label`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `array_multisort`.  This sorts as requested if you only have `fieldset` and `text`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, '#type'),  SORT_DESC,
                array_column($array, '#label'), SORT_ASC,
                $array);
```

Extract all `#type` values into an array sort descending and extract all `#label` values into an array sort ascending, sorting the original.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've never heard of `array_multisort` before, and it looks like something I could make use of next time. Sort of difficult to make it work with the way my code is working right now.